# How to speed up installation process in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I am making an installer which installs a folder on a user's machine. I am including a folder in my installer which is having the size 750MB. For this I have written the following code-

```
Section
  SetOutPath '$INSTDIR'
  File /r "c:\myfiles\*"
SectionEnd
```

While installing, this process takes long time to extract the files to installation directory. Is there any method or any option/way available to speed up this process?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a faster compression algorithm or disable compression altogether and see if that improves decompression. You could also use different methods to include the files in your installer, depending on whether the files are already compressed.

**Example:**

```
File uncompressed.wav
ReserveFile compressed.jpg
```